# PHP preg_match to extract a certain number from a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a multi line string like:

```
$msg = "Fix #1: This is a message
Fix #2
Fix #5";
```

I've tried a lot of patterns but none worked the way I want it to work.

What I want preg_match to do is to return an array with 1, 2 and 5. The pattern should check for all Fix #NUM and return all the NUM in an array.

Comment: *I've tried a lot of patterns* Just show us a few attempts

Comment: You're probably pretty close with some of your attempts.  Show us what you've tried and we can go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and simply match digits alone to return the desired results.

```
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $msg, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

If the matches need to be preceded by `Fix #`, you can use the following:

```
preg_match_all('/Fix\s+#\K\d+/', $msg, $matches);
```

This matches "Fix" followed by whitespace characters "one or more" times followed by #.

The `\K` escape sequence resets the starting point of the reported match and any previously consumed characters are no longer included.

Comment: `var_dump($matches[1])` :)

Comment: This works pretty good, can you please explain the second pattern? Especially the \K

Answer (score 1):

If `Fix #` has to be in-front of the number then something like this should do it:

```
/(?<=Fix\s+#)\d+/
```

Otherwise this is fine:

```
/\d+/
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `preg_match_all` with this `\d+` regex because `preg_match` would return only a  single match. It won't do a global match.